# Return generic promise from function call

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise

I have service  `IDataAccessService` which wrap `$resource` query call.

```
export interface IDataAccessService {
    getUserResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IUserResources>;
}
```

I use `IDataAccessService` in another service class `IUserService`.

```
export interface IUserService {
    getAll(): ng.IPromise<IUser[]>;
}
```

I write function `IUserService.getAll`, which will return `Promise<IUser[]>` and runs a query that fetches data from server with `IDataAccessService.getUserResource`, when data arrived I want sent data via Promise.

```
    getAll(): ng.IPromise<IUser[]> {

        var usersResource = this.dataAccessService.getUserResource();

        usersResource.query((users: Models.IUser) => {
            //return data via Promise
        });

        //return promise
    }
```

Comment: Could you please write what you have tried and what was the output or errors, just to clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at your code :

```
getAll(): ng.IPromise<IUser[]> {

        var usersResource = this.dataAccessService.getUserResource();

        usersResource.query((users: Models.IUser) => {
            //return data via Promise
        });

        //return promise
    }
```

First you probably meant `users: Models.IUser[]`. Based on that the final code should be:

```
getAll(): ng.IPromise<IUser[]> {

        var usersResource = this.dataAccessService.getUserResource();

        var def = $q.defer(); 

        let usersPromise = usersResource.query((users: Models.IUser) => {
            //return data via Promise
            def.resolve(users);
        });

        //return promise
        return def.promise;
    }
```

Learn more about `defer` here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: thank you, sorry I am newbie in angular, came from .net world, sometimes I am confuse.